# How can I figure out where set Django to do redirect like this?

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, learned a bit, but now I could not figure out what makes the code to do redirect like this:

In urls.py, the only line is

```
urlpatterns = patterns('main.site_views.static_views',
    url(r'^(?P<full_uri>[\w\/\-]+)/$', 'load_if_static_page', name='load-if-static-page'),
)
```

so I assume localhost:8000/testtest/ will go to the load_if_static_page, but instead, I got

```
Page not found (404)

Request Method:
GET 

Request URL:
https://localhost:8000/search/?item=testest/
```

so it seems some setting redirect the page to /search/, but I have no clue where to find it, any idea where should I check?

Thanks

Comment: you need to look for a view function called `load_if_static_page` in the `main.site_views.static_views` module.

Comment: yes, I checked it, it seems the url has changed to /search/?item=... before it reachs the view function

Comment: Hmm. Not sure without seeing more of the code.